# how to prove $\int_{0}^{a}B(t)dt\sim N(0,\frac{a^3}{3})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

Let $B(t)$ is Brownian Motion. I want to prove the integral $\int_{0}^{a}B(t)dt$ has normal distribution , $N(0,\frac{a^3}{3})$.
means $\int_{0}^{a}B(t)dt\sim N(0,\frac{a^3}{3})$

Comment: Try approximating the integral by Riemann sums.  What is the distribution of the Riemann sums?

Comment: Please do not [crosspost](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/76809/2970) identical questions simultaneously. Please see [this meta response](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a normal random variable as a barycenter of normal random variables. Its mean is $\int\limits_0^aE[B_t]\mathrm dt=$ $___$. Its variance is $\int\limits_0^a\int\limits_0^aE[B_tB_s]\mathrm dt\mathrm ds=\int\limits_0^a\int\limits_0^a\min(t,s)\mathrm dt\mathrm ds=$ $___$.

Comment: @did.I know all thing you write here, actully i want the answer of this integrals.thank you

Comment: Which $___$ are you unable to fill?

Comment: @did.the first integral.

Comment: Really? What is $E[B_t]$?

Comment: @did.I know it is equal zero but why?

Comment: ?? Why what? Why $E[B_t]=0$? Well, by *definition* of Brownian motion, each $B_t$ is gaussian centered...

Answer (score 0):

Ito's formula gives $aB(a) = \int_{0}^{a}B(t)dt + \int_{0}^{a}tdB(t)$

so $\int_{0}^{a}B(t)dt =aB(a) - \int_{0}^{a}tdB(t)  = \int_{0}^{a}(a-t) dB(t)$.

and for a deterministic function $f$, $\int_{0}^{a}f(t)dB(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \int_{0}^{a}f^2(t)dt)$